# Convert XML text to class object c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to convert `XML` string to **Class** object in `c#`, but getting exception. For this I tried the below code to convert `xml` string to **Class** object.

```
    string xmlString = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
      <WdashboardRoot xmlns='urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x14027120'>
         <Whsedashboard1>
           <DocumentType> Order </DocumentType>
           <OrderNumber> S - ORD101006 </OrderNumber>
           <CustomerNo> 10000 </CustomerNo>
           <CustomerName> Adatum Corporation </CustomerName>
              <ShippingAgentCode> UPS </ShippingAgentCode>
              <ShippingAgentService> GROUND </ShippingAgentService>
              <ReqShipmentDate> 04 / 02 / 21 </ReqShipmentDate>
              <PromiseShipmentDate> 04 / 02 / 21 </PromiseShipmentDate>
              <Status> Pending Orders </Status>
               </Whsedashboard1>
             </WdashboardRoot> ";
    
                Serializer ser = new Serializer();
                WdashboardRoot Wdashboard = ser.Deserialize<WdashboardRoot>(xmlString);
                var xmlOutputData = ser.Serialize<WdashboardRoot>(Wdashboard);
    
     [Serializable]
        public class WdashboardRoot
        { 
            public Whsedashboard1[] Whsedashboard1 
        }

 [Serializable]
    public class Whsedashboard1
    {
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAgentCode { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAgentService { get; set; }
        public string ReqShipmentDate { get; set; }
        public string PromiseShipmentDate { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
    
     public class Serializer
        {
            public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    
                using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
                {
                    return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
                }
            }
    
            public string Serialize<T>(T ObjectToSerialize)
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());
    
                using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
                {
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, ObjectToSerialize);
                    return textWriter.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Can you please suggest me to convert this `xml` string to **Class** object.

Really appreciate if someone helps.

Comment: Not my downvote, but what problem are you having?

Comment: @MattEvans It's not converting into `class` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got working with minor changes.  See below

```
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x14027120")]
    public class WdashboardRoot
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public Whsedashboard1[] Whsedashboard1 { get; set; } 
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: But the values are not showing in the array. Have you checked?

Comment: I put a breakpoint at the end of main and then checked the variable Wdashboard which had all the elements.

Comment: All the variables have data? the data is not extracting i.e null..

Comment: I added a picture of results

Comment: Great!.. Can you post full code here. Please

Comment: It is your code with only the one class changed.  The only thing I did was to take the code and put inside main. Your classes I put in the top level namespace of a console project.